# Common expression for request and order

Tags: nouns, synonyms

We are designing an automated ordering system which concerns itself mainly with two entities:

- Requests, which express the need of a customer to place an order in the near future
- Orders, which are sent to third-party suppliers

What noun embraces both Requests and Orders, i.e. a substitute for X in the following sentences?

- A request is an X
- An order is an X

Ideally, X is a term that is 'natural' within the commodity domain. If possible, the fact that an item is being shipped as a consequence of X being processed should be evident.

Answer (score 1):

In my programs I use *job* for the overall process which will result in something being provisioned, emailed, or shipped - regardless of source: public web site, phone, recurring subscription, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> [**imperative**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/imperative) (Sense 3, Grammar) *of, relating to, or constituting the mood that expresses a **command** or **request**.*

But OP's exact context doesn't really correspond to any specific "category" recognised by English - the two examples are simply sub-categories of ***order*** (*pending*, and *placed*) There of course are other types of "order" in this general sense, such as a [pro forma order](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7203839_pro-forma-order_.html).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think `imperative` is the term I was looking for. I extended my question hoping it would help you see why.

Comment: @blubb: I know. But people who see your question title will understand that sense as most likely what you're after, since there *is* no meaningful term other than "order" for what you actually want.

Comment: @blubb: You might want to reconsider your use of "request" here. I'm not an accountant, so I can't offhand explain what if any difference there is between *pending* and *pro-forma* orders, but I've programmed lots of accounts-related systems over the years, and I never encountered "request" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing documentation for the system, I'd suggest choosing from the word "action", "event", or "transaction". If you're writing the specification for the system, I'd look for different terminology, perhaps "order", or "advance order" where you have "request", and "urgent order", where you have "order".

Answer (score 0):

I would say that **Order** is the right word.

A request is the placing of an order, and the order is the result of the request